# How is this invalid syntax? Else in a while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Ive created a few objects, a deck, cards, and a player. I want to deal the cards to each player until the deck is empty

```
players = int(input('How many players?'))
names = []

for a_name in range(0,players):
    player_name = input("Player's name?")
    names.append(player_name)

names[0] = Player(names[0])
names[1] = Player(names[1])
names[2] = Player(names[2])
names[3] = Player(names[3])
names[4] = Player(names[4])


deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()

cards_left = int(len(deck.cards))

while cards_left > 0:
    names[0].Draw(deck)
    names[1].Draw(deck)
    names[2].Draw(deck)
    names[3].Draw(deck)
    names[4].Draw(deck)
    else:
        pass
```

It gives me this error. How is this invalid syntax? Am I using while and else correctly?

```
 File "<ipython-input-1-7a4afb61293c>", line 77
    else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your "else" would need to be lined up with the "while" statement.

Comment: Why do you even have an `else` there? What did you expect that to do?

Comment: `else` can't be paired with a while, only with a `if`. In your case you should just remove the `else: pass`.

Comment: @altermetax: `else` actually can be paired with `while` in Python, but doing so doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @altermetax: `else` pairs just fine with `while`. The `else` block runs when the `while` exits due to the condition being false (as opposed to exiting due to a `break`, which would bypass the `else` block). Given there is no `break` involved though, the `else` block is equivalent to just putting it's contents immediately after the loop without `else` control (they'll always be executed when the loop condition becomes false).

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You screwed up the indentation. In python else goes at the same indentation level as the corresponding if or while statement, not inside it.

Note that else with a while loop executes when the condition becomes false, so it's only really useful if you have break statements in the loop and you have some statements that you want to run on loop completion but bot on a break.